# Perl read file vs traverse array Performance

Tags: perl

I need to test lines in a file against multiple values

What are the difference in terms of time between opening a file and reading line by line each time vs opening the file once placing it in an array and traversing the array each time?

Comment: IO is always slower then memory.

Comment: This is purely a performance question. It has nothing to do with algorithmic complexity ("big-O").

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To expand upon what @mpacpec said in his comment, file IO is always slower than memory read/writes.  But there's more to the story.  "Test lines in a file against multiple values" can be interpreted in a lot of ways, so without knowing more about what exactly you are trying to do, then no one can tell you anything more specifically.  So the answer is, "It depends".  It depends on the file size, what you're testing and how often, and how you're testing.

However, pragmatically speaking, based upon my understanding of what you've said, you'll have to read the whole file one way or another, and you'll have to test every line, one way or another.  Do what's easiest to write/read/understand, and see if that's fast enough.  If it isn't, you have a much more useful baseline from which to ask the question.  Personally, I'd start with a linewise read and test loop and work from there, simply because I think that'd be easier and faster to write correctly.

Make it work, then make it fast :)

Comment: What about mmap? Does reading a file that's mapped to the proccess's vm is still slower than memory read/write?

Comment: If the bits are on the disk, they must, at some point, be read off the disk and into memory.  When you read memory that's mapped to a file, at some level, file IO will occur.  There is no way around that.  Depending on how it's implemented, it might be faster.  What's broken that you're trying to fix?

Comment: Nothings broken and I'm not a newbie programmer. I was thinking out loud. The code was working, I want to improve it. Right now its a loop that reopens the file at each iteration which just doesn't seem like a good idea

Comment: Sorry, didn't mean to infer otherwise, and apologies if I came of as condescending.  Reopening the file is certainly a redundancy you can omit--in fact, I can imagine at least one scenario where that leads to occasional failures.  My suspicion based on what you've said is that the performance characteristics will be related to the total number of tests (rather than the number of lines).

Comment: @Jabda: Whether you are working line-by-line, or slurping the file, it *should* be possible to arrange to only loop through all the contents once, unless there is something that prevents it within the tests (e.g. second test uses some aggregate values from the first test in its logic)

Comment: If you can provide a little detail about what the tests are, I'm invested enough now to compare a few things :)

Answer (score 1):

Provided in the former case you can do all the tests you need on each line (rather than re-reading file each time), then the two approaches should be *roughly* the same speed and I/O, CPU efficiency (ignoring second-order effects such as whether the disk IO gets distracted by other processes more easily). However, the latter case - reading whole file - may hit memory limits for large files, which may cause it to lose performance dramatically or even fail.

The main cost of processing the file line by line is loss of flexibility - for instance if you need to cross-reference the lines, it would not be easy (whilst if they are all in memory, the code to do that would be simpler and faster).